# Take only one side of a list of lists and add to a new list

Tags: python, list

Say I have multiple lists of lists. Something like this:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[56,32],[34,244]]
list2 = [[43,21],[30,1],[19,3]]
list3 = [[1,3],[8,21],[9,57]]
```

I want to create two new lists:

```
right_side = [2,32,244,21,1,3,3,21,57]
left_side = [1,56,34,43,30,19,1,8,9]
```

All sub-lists have only two values. And all big lists (list1,list2,list3) have the same number of values as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: if numpy is an option, you can [slice](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-ndarray-slice/)  the array. Otherwise: concatenate and loop?

Comment: `right_side = [i[1] for i in (list1 + list2 + list3)]`, and `left_side = [i[0] for i in (list1 + list2 + list3)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using zip built-in function you get tuples:

```
left_side, right_side = zip(*list1, *list2, *list3)
```

And if you really need lists:

```
left_side, right_side = map(list, zip(*list1, *list2, *list3))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. numpy is overkill

Answer (score 2):

The below seems to work.

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [56, 32], [34, 244]]
list2 = [[43, 21], [30, 1], [19, 3]]
list3 = [[1, 3], [8, 21], [9, 57]]

left = []
right = []
lst = [list1, list2, list3]
for l in lst:
    for ll in l:
        left.append(ll[0])
        right.append(ll[1])
print(f'Left: {left}')
print(f'Right: {right}')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any issues with importing some standard libraries, you might achieve the goal as follows:

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

right_side = list(map(itemgetter(1), itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3)))
left_side = list(map(itemgetter(0), itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3)))
```

Output of the due `print`s shall be:

```
[2, 32, 244, 21, 1, 3, 3, 21, 57]
[1, 56, 34, 43, 30, 19, 1, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
All =  list1+list2+list3
All = np.array(All)
print(All[:,1].tolist())
```

Gives right elemnst #

```
[2, 32, 244, 21, 1, 3, 3, 21, 57]
```

To get left #

```
print(All[:,0].tolist())
```

Gives #

```
[1, 56, 34, 43, 30, 19, 1, 8, 9]
>>>
```